Structure of $p$-primary Abelian groups without Divisorial Elements
Let $A$ be a $p$-primary (in particular, torsion) Abelian group ($p$ prime). Assume that $A[p]=\{a \in A \vert pa=0\}$ is finite and that there are no nontrivial infinitely $p$-divisible elements, ie $\bigcap_n p^nA=\{0\}$.
Why does it follow that $A$ is finite (... or equivalently in light of classification of fin. gen. Ab groups, finitely generated?
(This claim is about $p$- primary component of Shafarevich group from Milne's Elliptic Curves (REMARK 5.2, p 127, here available)

(I'm assuming that you meant to write $\bigcap_n p^n A=0$, as the alternative makes little sense.)
First, we can show that $A$ is bounded, i.e. that $p^nA=0$ for some $n$ already. If this is not the case, we may find an infinite sequence of elements $(x_i)$ of orders $p^i$. But then, the elements $p^{i-1}x_i$ are each of order $p$ and so - since there are only finitely many options - at least one of them must occur infinitely often in the list, which is a contradiction (to the intersection $\bigcap_n p^n A$ being trivial).
If you are aware of the fact that bounded abelian groups are direct sums of cyclic groups, you can finish the argument easily from here - any such direct sum decomposition can only contain finitely many nonzero summands to allow $A[p]$ to be finite.
However, if you don't know this, we can still finish the proof without too much trouble:
Let $n$ be minimal such that $p^nA=0$. Now, observe that $B=pA$ still satisfies all your conditions (as $B[p]\subseteq A[p]$) but satisfies $p^{n-1}B=0$ already. By induction on $n$, we conclude that $B$ must therefore be finite. But then, since $B\simeq A/A[p]$, $A$ must be finite as well, which finishes the proof.
